# What position is best for Kha'zix? Mid, Top or Jungle (Preseason)

Tags: league-of-legends

I'd like to main Kha'zix but I'm not sure which position I should play him to use his skill-set most effectively.

Comment: It would be great if the question were about K6 during Season 4.

Answer (score 1):

Kha'Zix is definitely best as a jungler.  He is still a very common ban at high ELO, but this is because he is so strong in the jungle.  He isn't banned for fear of lane Kha'Zix.

His debuff that lets him do additional damage to separated targets allows for very strong counter jungling.  You can sneak into their jungle and easily kill the other jungler and get out pretty often.  Also, it is great for ganks because often the enemy will run away from minions to get back to their turret so they aren't stuck facing a 2v1.  This also gives a good opportunity to jump on them with the increased damage bonus.

As a mid, he simply can't take advantage of his debuff because the lane is so small.  He is good at roaming though and so taking him mid is definitely a good secondary role for him.

As a top, he just will get outperformed by most tops because they are typically tankier and can survive through more extended trades which happen more often in the longer top lane.

TL;DR; Jungle is by far his best role hands down.

Answer (score 0):

Assassins have seen the most popularity mid as of late because of their ability to burst the squishier lane opponents.

In addition to where he's been seen in pro play (Was a top tier mid for a while but fell out of favor altogether to some extent), S4 so far has revealed a much tougher to clear jungle, which has been a problem for carry junglers like Kha'Zix, Rengar, Nocturne, etc. Top lane is a good option, but as a burst assassin you'll have better matchups mid.

Comment: I'd agree that he's best placed mid for now. In the jungle, his ganks aren't particularly strong if the enemy has escapes or CC, so he's quite a situational pick there. In top lane he doesn't get much opportunity to get ahead against more tanky opponents. Mid will typically pit him against more easily assassinated opponents, and he can roam after pushing lane to pick up kills and assists elsewhere in order to snowball. Try AD marks and Quints, and a Fort Pot start for surprise first blood on mid at level 2/3!

Comment: What?... Mid is no longer in the assassin meta.  The only assassin still commonly played in mid is LeBlanc.  The rest of been mostly phased out due to the Exhaust buffs and popular Utility/Wave clear mids.  Also, Recently Nocturne has recently become large in the current meta.  Kha'Zix is often banned because of his strength from the jungle...

Comment: @dphil well yeah I wrote the original comment in November

Comment: Ahhhh I see.  I never really look at dates.  It just popped this discussion up as recent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no real lane where he's strongest since he's easily countered, but the lane he's most played in is mid.

He has the potential to oneshot AD and AP carries and being midlane allows him to roam top and bot while farming a lane (unlike a jungler). But since he can be played everywhere the strongest lane will be the one that you can play best. If you are a midlaner that doesn't know how to roam you won't be that useful as a mid kha so you may better play top where you can farm up and try to 1v1 the enemy toplaner. Maybe if you have problems with facing a champion in 1v1 you should go jungle and just farm jungle creeps and gank lanes for a secure kill. It's really what you can play best. And just because the Pros and high elo players play him mid mostly, you don't have to play him mid aswell. Most people forget that they aren't pros and that pros play completely different from normal players and soloqueue.

You should just try him on every lane and master him on that one you like most since you can carry games with him on every lane.

Answer (score 0):

The situation after patch 4.5 (mid season 4):

Short answer: top or jungle.

I don't consider mid since usually you'll be facing a mage with lots of pokers in mid. Jungle will maximize your gank chances since you don't have to worry about your turret being pushed.

Plus his Q and E got nerfed recently while R got buffed so during the LCS he was more played as a bruiser rather than an assassin as before.

Comment: I disagree with the not mid recommendation, as mid isn't just about pokers. Burst assassins do pretty well in mid as well.